# Wired Method not taking values passed from meta xml

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

I have a lightning Web component that takes input value from lightning page using meta xml.
The value passed from meta xml, is getting passed to wired method to get total record count.

DefaultObject value gets passed from lightning page. but it looks like it's not taking it.
But if I hardcod the value like

JS:

```
import gettotalcount from '@salesforce/apex/LWCController.gettotalcount';

    wiredcountResults;
        @wire(gettotalcount, {objName: '$this.DefaultObject', fieldsToDisplay : 'Id,Name'}) totalcount(result) {
            console.log('>>> wired result.data... ' + result.data);
            this.wiredcountResults = result;
            if (result.data != undefined) {
                this.totalRecordCount = result.data;
                console.log('>>> total count in totalcount method... ' + this.totalRecordCount);
                if (result.data > 0)
                    this.wrapperListtrue = true;
                else {
                    this.totalRecordCount = 0;
                    this.wrapperListtrue = true;
                    console.log('tota' + this.totalRecordCount);
                }
            } else if (result.error) {
                
                this.error = result.error;
                this.totalRecordCount = 0;
                console.log('>>> total count error in totalcount method... ' + this.totalRecordCount);
            }
        }
```

It looks like it's passing the value from meta xml file. If I pass hard coded value, it's returning results. like:

```
@wire(gettotalcount, {objName: 'Account', fieldsToDisplay : 'Id,Name'}) totalcount(result)
```

Comment: `$` prefix tells the wire service to treat the suffix as a property of the class i.e. `$recordId` would be evaluated as `this.recordId` during execution. So, `$this.DefaultObject` is incorrect because this would get evaluated into `this.this.DefaultObject`.  Also, can you elaborate on **"values passed from meta xml"**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your information, you should try passing the parameter to the wired method like:

```
@wire(gettotalcount, {objName: '$DefaultObject', fieldsToDisplay : 'Id,Name'})
totalcount(result) {
  // Your code here
}
```